# Is the data transfer between BigQuery and client lib secured?

Tags: java, google-bigquery

Is the data transfer between BigQuery and client lib secured?

I have a requirement to transfer a little bit of data which cannot fly over the wire without any protection. My application is outside GCP so my first thought is whether Java libs from BigQuery support some kind of transfer encryption by default?

Answer (score 2):

> Is the data transfer between BigQuery and client lib secured?

Yes, it's, By default all connections to BigQuery are via https and secure.

Easy to see this if you use [BigQuery API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query) and check the `curl` headers (Note the use of https)

```
curl --request POST \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/projectId/queries' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"query":"select 5"}' \
  --compressed
```

Actually to disable SSL validation you need to define this on your call, as an example, in [BigQuery CLI](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference) you need to do this `--disable_ssl_validation` if you want to disable ssl